# Update marker shape of a scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib, animation, scatter-plot, marker

A scatter plot object has a method called .set_color to update the colors of the markers and .set_offsets to update their position but how can I update the marker shapes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A scatter plot returns a path collection, it contains the paths of the markers. In order to change the marker shape you need to set the path to the new marker path.

For [built-in markers](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers), these paths can be obtained from the [`MarkerStyle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.html#matplotlib-markers-markerstyle) class. For custom markers see my [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65412578/3944322).

**Example** - scatter plot with *dot* markers later changed to *plus* markers:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle

sp = plt.scatter([1,2],[1,2], marker='.')

new_marker = MarkerStyle("+")
sp.set_paths((new_marker.get_path(),))
sp.set_sizes([8])

plt.show()
```

[image]

The only caveat is that you need to set the marker size too, by default the new markers are plotted rather big.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. How would I go about setting different markerstyles for different markers? (e.g. I have 10 points, and want to set the first 5 '+' and the second 5 'D')

Comment: it's easiest to first plot the first five points, then the rest: `plt.scatter(x[:5], y[:5], marker='+')`  `plt.scatter(x[5:], y[5:], marker='D')`  `plt.show()`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I have accepted your answer, but can't upvote as my reputation is <15.