# How to change dot types in Python prince

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, pca

I'm using `prince` for a principal component analysis:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '{:.6f}'.format(x))
X=pd.DataFrame(data=[
[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
],
columns=pd.Series(['toilNnseC','iClRnroscde','DT','sERH','ioRgL','BN','NN','OSP','hntoPy','R','FR','MSV','Uwknnon','AcTESK','ebmndgied','emlma','arsngm','fitfd']),
index=pd.Series(['Asaf_r9h1','1vam_9anAbal','t_t5ggoB1a','l9arrB1teohi_','ie_Bd15','rd1ita9B_t','5er1_aCllr','_9orsCa1n','stoC_5a1r','Chyr7a1_','C1_rah8y','a17k_lrC','ko_61oC','mCehtpspo71_ri','p8motpr_Cis1eh','ncroro1C8a_','71D_ia','9seDa1_nelin','na1Do_7','De__1aL8uVny_','rasdee8_nFn1','nla17inFn_io','e_ar9usGl1','Gdn7io_w1o','1uu9Gt_knu','a20r_tH','e5_H1','nHoog7ndre_1oo','_l1a5Iqb','a_c7J1nsok','yo8_1reL','_16Luo','1eungaM_8','et6rM_e1gz','M1zu9e_k','_se18reMnos','P1apai_9hnrt','yat_lPi5J_leeelktaa1','P1etll_o5Layd_','2silP1er_','_s6nPtaei1','7oa_1Pdas','_8o1Ry','1ne5dRoys_','ehesu_Sw1rcg7','3ir_n1eSh','Sh11_on','Tankoa7_1','_ana6aT1n','o_19T','o1aTz9_p','_217rTn0a','_1nuT6g','1Veceu_ht9ar','_aY1n9','a81aYvrdz_a','_1Yu1','ogZh1n9_']),
)
X.columns.rename('Columns', inplace=True)
X.index.rename('Rows', inplace=True)

import prince
ca = prince.CA(n_components=2,n_iter=3,copy=True,check_input=True,engine='auto',random_state=42)
ca = ca.fit(X)
ca.row_coordinates(X)
ca.column_coordinates(X)
ax = ca.plot_coordinates(X=X,ax=None,figsize=(6, 6),x_component=0,y_component=1,show_row_labels=False,show_col_labels=False)

fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('figure01.png')
```

Here is the result:

[image]

My problem is that the journal which will publish this figure requires different symbols for the dots of the two classes (for which I'm using colors). How can I change the shape of dots? (to have, for example  crosses, or lozenges, or squares…).

Comment: @Mr. T: I just did. And this time it is the complete code…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrospectively change the markers (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65422142/8881141) and say thank you with an upvote):

```
...
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
...
ca = prince.CA(n_components=2,n_iter=3,copy=True,check_input=True,engine='auto',random_state=42)
ca = ca.fit(X)
ca.row_coordinates(X)
ca.column_coordinates(X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

ca.plot_coordinates(X=X,
                    ax=ax,
                    x_component=0,
                    y_component=1,
                    show_row_labels=False,
                    show_col_labels=False,
                    color="black"
                  )



markerlist = ["o", "v", "S", "H"]
for item, marker in zip(ax.collections, markerlist): 
    if type(item) == PathCollection:        
        new_marker = MarkerStyle(marker)   
        item.set_paths((new_marker.get_path(),))
        item.set_sizes([10])
    
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that prince puts the markers behind bars. You can prevent that if you don't like it and add `zorder=10` to the `ca.plot_coordinates(...)` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "marker" after splitting rows and columns:

```
#coordinates
x = ca.row_coordinates(X)
y = ca.column_coordinates(X)

#labels
labels = ca.explained_inertia_
x_label = 'Component 0 ('+ str(round(labels[0]*100,2))+'% inertia)'
y_label = 'Component 1 ('+ str(round(labels[1]*100,2))+'% inertia)'

#figure
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 8), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = plt.scatter(x[0], x[1], marker='^', label='Row')
ax2 = plt.scatter(y[0], y[1], marker='x', label='Columns')
plt.xlabel(x_label)
plt.ylabel(y_label)
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.axhline(y=0, color='k')
plt.axvline(x=0, color='k')
```

I'm not sure it's the best way but it works

[image]

Comment: Isn't the point that instead of different colors, different markers should be used?

Comment: In fact, no. The journal wants different markers: for example a triangle for the class "rows" and a circle for the class "columns". With the code given by FrancescoMartino I have the same problem: only color distinguishes the classes…

Comment: Pardon, I misunderstood. I edit the answer

Comment: Cheeky approach. I like that.

Comment: But now I lost the little box explaining the correspondence between marker and class…

Comment: Don't worry, I completed the graph

Comment: You shouldn't write `ax = plt.scatter(...)`  because `scatter()` returns a collection of points, not an `ax` (note that contrary to the matplotlib code here, many seaborn and pandas plot commands do return an `ax`).